# Why the result shows an array since the arguments are passing two numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion

I was trying to solve a problem with Javascript from the freeCodeCamp. The Heading of the problem is "Use Recursion to Create a Range of Numbers". I could not fix it according to the problem descriptions, accurately. Then, I tried to understand the probable solution from the internet. I found a exact solution and modified by myself for better understanding. And the compiler accept the answer! But I really can not understand now why it finally returns an array since it will return a number when both startNum & endNum are the same. Can anyone explain the program please?

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  console.log(startNum);
  console.log(endNum);

  if (endNum - startNum === 0) {
    console.log(startNum);

    return [startNum];

  } else {
    var numbers = rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1);
    console.log(numbers);
    //numbers.unshift(endNum);
    numbers.push(endNum);
    return numbers;
  }
}
console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5));
```

Link of the problem:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/use-recursion-to-create-a-range-of-numbers

Comment: _"it will return a number when both startNum & endNum are the same"_. No, this is not a number, it's an Array: `return [startNum];`. A number would be `return startNum;`

Comment: `endNum - startNum === 0` is more clearly written as `endNum === startNum`

Comment: But you shouldn't return a single number, because the recursive caller expects it to return an array so it can call `numbers.push(endNum)`

Answer (score 0):

> But I really can not understand now why it finally returns an array since it will return a number when both `startNum` & `endNum` are the same.

No, it doesn't.

```
return [startNum];
```

returns an array. The `[]` around `startNum` creates an array with the value of `startNum` as its single element.

You apparently misread that line as

```
return startNum;
```